# How to do transition as expected with axis in D3

Tags: d3.js

All:

I am pretty new to D3 transition, I wonder how can I not apply length transition on axis tick lines when I switch data?

My code is like:

```js
var data1 = [1,2,3,4]
var data2 = [1,4,8,12]

function draw(data){

 var svg = d3.select(".chart svg");
 if(svg.empty()){
  svg = d3.select(".chart")
    .append("svg");
  svg.append("g")
  .classed("yaxis", true)
 }
 svg.attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 300);
 var axisg = svg.select("g.yaxis")
  .attr("transform", function(){
   return "translate(40, 20)";
  })
 var scale = d3.scale.linear();
 scale.domain(d3.extent(data)).range([300-40, 0]);
 var axis = d3.svg.axis();
 axis.scale(scale).orient("left")/*.ticks(5)*/;
 axisg.transition().duration(1500).ease("sin-in-out").call(axis)
 .selectAll("line")
   .attr("x2", 300-40)
   .style("stroke", "black")
   .style("stroke-width", "1px");
 axisg.select("path").style("fill", "none")

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="draw(data1)">Data1</button>
<button onclick="draw(data2)">Data2</button>

<div class="chart"></div>
```

Comment: So on initial load you want the lines to "grow" from left to right?  But on data updates you just want slide in the new range and not "grow" the lines?

Comment: This is the line that applies the transition: `axisg.transition().duration(1500).ease("sin-in-out").call(axis)`. Just change it to `axisg.call(axis)` if you don't want the transition. Or use an if/else statement to decide when to apply/not apply the transition depending on your use case.